# MySQL + htaccess mod_rewrite?

Tags: mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a proxy-like short domain in conjunction with my site. The short domain is hrci.me and the long domain is reachchallenges.infectionist.com. hrci.me uses mod_rewrite and has a rule that pretty much does a simple redirect from hrci.me to reachchallenges.infectionist.com, so for example:

```
hrci.me/x/y.php
```

would redirect to

```
reachchallenges.infectionist.com/x/y.php
```

Simple as can be. On the main site I have more rules that further rewrite the URL, prettifying it. One example is a script on my site, challenges.php, which accepts a single parameter, *chid*, which is the challenge ID linked to more information in the database. Passed as a parameterized script it would look like this: `/challenge.php?chid=123`, but after it's rewritten it looks like this: `/challenge/123/Challenge+Title/`, where `Challenge+Title` is the actual title of the item from the database.  There's also a different way you can call the same page, like this: `/ch123`, so in essence you can access the page 3 different ways:

```
1. /challenge.php?chid=123
2. /challenge/123/Challenge+Title/
3. /ch123
```

This actually works perfectly, the issue that I have is that I want the URLs that are redirected from hrci.me to first be rewritten to look like #2 above, so the user would click hrci.me/ch123 and the htaccess file would read the database, get the title for challenge id 123, rewrite the url to `/challenge/123/Challenge+Title/` and then redirect it to reachchallenges.infectionist.com. Is something like this possible?  Is it possible to read from a MySQL database using htaccess in this way?

**UPDATE**:
I added this to my httpd.conf file:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=*****,user=*****,pass=*****,dbname=*****"
RewriteMap hrci "dbd:SELECT title FROM challenges WHERE id = %s"
RewriteLog "/home/halo2freeek/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Then added a RewriteRule to one of my subdomains that I don't really use (to test it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ch([0-9]{1,4})(/)?$ http://reachchallenges.infectionist.com/challenge/$1/${hrci:$1} [R=301,L]
```

When I visit this path on the subdomain:

/ch232

It should redirect to:

http://reachchallenges.infectionist.com/challenge/232/Challenge+Title

But instead it redirects to:

http://reachchallenges.infectionist.com/challenge/232/

Without the title. Am I doing something wrong?  Do I have to specify `RewriteEngine On` in the httpd.conf file?

**UPDATE 2**: Ok, so I added the `RewriteEngine On` line and saved, when I tried to restart Apache I got this error:

```
RewriteMap: file for map hrci not found:/dh/apache2/apache2-ps54462/dbd:SELECT title FROM challenges WHERE id = %s
```

It looks like it's completely ignoring the `dbd` part and trying to read the whole thing as a file name. Now I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) everything is possible:

```
RewriteMap examplemap prg:/path/to/file.php
RewriteRule (.*) ${examplemap:$1}
```

You can use [mod_dbd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dbd.html) as well:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=localhost,user=db_user,pass=password,dbname=db"
RewriteMap myquery "dbd:select new_url from rewrite where old_url = %s" 
RewriteRule (.*) ${myquery:$1}
```

Comment: You just forgot to mention that `RewriteMap` directive CANNOT be placed in .htaccess -- only in server config / virtual host context. If OP cannot edit those files (on shared hosting, for example) then it is useless for him.

Comment: No, I didn't. I let the inquirer discover it himself. Moreover, you'd have to restart Apache every time you change that script. But still, if one wants it, he can get it.

Comment: _"But still, if one wants it, he can get it"_ -- True. I would just mentioned it anyway (personal preference).

Comment: I have a virtual private server through Dreamhost, so I can edit the httpd.conf file, but I don't know where to put the RewriteMap directive.  Also, in sanmai's example, how would file.php get the chid parameter? Edit: I looked up RewriteMap in the Apache docs and I saw this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd which looks like it allows SQL queries, could I use this instead of a php script? Something like "SELECT title FROM challenges WHERE id = %s", would that work with a MySQL database?

Comment: Yes, that is. It looks easy to configure and much easier to use than `RewriteMap prg`

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and tried out the dbd method, I've updated my main post with more information.

Comment: Please post another question.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329212/problems-with-rewritemap-maptype-dbd