# Problems with RewriteMap MapType dbd

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

Continuing from another discussion here:

[MySQL + htaccess mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320979/mysql-htaccess-mod-rewrite)

Where I was asked to start another question.

I added this to my httpd.conf file:

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=*****,user=*****,pass=*****,dbname=*****"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap hrci "dbd:SELECT title FROM challenges WHERE id = %s"
```

When I tried to restart Apache I got this error:

```
RewriteMap: file for map hrci not found:/dh/apache2/apache2-ps54462/dbd:SELECT title FROM challenges WHERE id = %s
```

It looks like it's completely ignoring the `dbd` part and trying to read the whole thing as a file name. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I tried simplifying this and just using a straight text file for the map:

RewriteMap hrci txt:/home/username/rewrite.txt

There is a text file in the root directory that contains simply this:

232 The+Pillar+of+Autumn+LASO

And finally, I have my rewrite rule:

RewriteRule ^ch([0-9]{1,4})(/)?$ http://reachchallenges.infectionist.com/challenge/$1/${hrci:$1} [R=301,L]

So visiting the path `ch232` should redirect to `/challenge/232/The+Pillar+of+Autumn+LASO`, but instead it just redirects to `/challenge/232/`, no title. What the heck am I doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the reason why the dbd part in the RewriteMap is not working (at least for me) is that it should be working only from apache 2.3+. For my apache2.2, it does not work.